# Problems with tikz tree growth on secondary levels in trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, trees, tikz-trees

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1.3cm, sibling distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1.2cm, sibling distance=1cm]
\node[bag] {$S_i$}
    child[grow=left] {
        node[bag] {$S_{i+1}^{(1)}$}        
            child {
                node[end, label=left:
                    {$S$}] {}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$W$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=left:
                    {$S$}] {}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$B$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=left:
                    {$S$}] {}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$B$}
            }
            edge from parent[-latex]
            node[above] {$W$}
    }
    child[grow=right] {
        node[bag] {$A$}        
        child {
                node[bag] {$ \dots S_{i+1}^{(k_1)}$}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$w$}
        }
        child {
                node[bag] {$S_{i+1}^{(2)}$}
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(2)(k_{\dots})}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(2)(2)}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$w$}
        }
        child {
                node[bag] {$S_{i+1}^{(1)}$}
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(1)(k_{\dots})}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(1)(2)}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(1)(1)}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$w$}
        }
        edge from parent[-latex]    
            node[above] {$B$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Having in preamble

```
\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=1.5em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{end} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]
```

My problem is that the branch on the right generates collisions and the tree does not expand automatically.

Basically speaking nodes do overlap. How can i avoid this???

Thanks

Comment: Please complete your code to make it compilable; as it is now, no one knows how you defined the `bag` and `end` styles, for example.

Comment: Very sorry, forgot about it

Comment: @Andry This is still not compilable code: put everything into a `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}...\begin{document}...\end{document}` This way people can play with your code more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to give appropriate values to `sibling distance` for the appropriate levels; in your example, the problematic levels are the second and the third:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped,bag/.style={draw},end/.style={draw}]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1.3cm, sibling distance=4cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=2.2cm, sibling distance=1.5cm]
\node[bag] {$S_i$}
    child[grow=left,level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm}] {
        node[bag] {$S_{i+1}^{(1)}$}        
            child {
                node[end, label=left:
                    {$S$}] {}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$W$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=left:
                    {$S$}] {}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$B$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=left:
                    {$S$}] {}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$B$}
            }
            edge from parent[-latex]
            node[above] {$W$}
    }
    child[grow=right] {
        node[bag] {$A$}        
        child {
                node[bag] {$ \dots S_{i+1}^{(k_1)}$}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$w$}
        }
        child {
                node[bag] {$S_{i+1}^{(2)}$}
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(2)(k_{\dots})}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(2)(2)}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$w$}
        }
        child {
                node[bag] {$S_{i+1}^{(1)}$}
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(1)(k_{\dots})}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(1)(2)}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(1)(1)}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$w$}
        }
        edge from parent[-latex]    
            node[above] {$B$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you could also be interested in the `edge from parent path` option to control where the arrows will connect the nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped,bag/.style={draw},end/.style={draw},
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=2cm, sibling distance=4cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=2.2cm, sibling distance=1.5cm]
\node[bag] {$S_i$}
    child[grow=left,level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) -- (\tikzchildnode.east)}] {
        node[bag] {$S_{i+1}^{(1)}$}        
            child {
                node[end, label=left:
                    {$S$}] {}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$W$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=left:
                    {$S$}] {}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$B$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=left:
                    {$S$}] {}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$B$}
            }
            edge from parent[-latex]
            node[above] {$W$}
    }
    child[grow=right] {
        node[bag] {$A$}        
        child {
                node[bag] {$ \dots S_{i+1}^{(k_1)}$}
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$w$}
        }
        child {
                node[bag] {$S_{i+1}^{(2)}$}
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(2)(k_{\dots})}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(2)(2)}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$w$}
        }
        child {
                node[bag] {$S_{i+1}^{(1)}$}
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(1)(k_{\dots})}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(1)(2)}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                child {
                     node[bag] {$S_{i+2}^{(1)(1)}$}
                     edge from parent[-latex]
                     node[above] {u}
                }
                edge from parent[-latex]
                node[above] {$w$}
        }
        edge from parent[-latex]    
            node[above] {$B$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]